# Can't understand a mysql query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I had a question yesterday about ordering a mysql query by rand().  And I got a good answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16597706/2333744

THe code for the answer is below.

```
create temporary table results as
(Select *, @rn := @rn + 1 as rn, rand() as therand
from table1 inner join
  table2
  on table1.in = table2.in cross join
    (select @rn := 0) const
where table1.T = A
);

select *
from results
where therand < 1000/@rn
order by therand
limit 500;
```

I understand everything except for

```
cross join (select @rn : = 0) const
```

I'm not sure what this is doing and if its important.  When I remove it I get no performance change.  Can anyone understand this part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

frankly, all this does is to reset the @rn variable. Is is "packed" into a select to avoid running 2 queries. The const means that it is constant, hence only evaluated once.

You could run into trouble when you remove it and add further queries into a single transaction.

Best regards

Zsolt

Comment: why does it need the cross join?

Comment: it does not. You could use other joins too. Or remove it alltogether and send a second query deleting the var.

Comment: Ok I've tested it out.  I'm setting @rn to 0 before every query.  Will this work if I have 10 concurrent connections.  Do they all have the same @ rn variable?

Answer (score 1):

The [***User-Defined Variable***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) `@rn` used in this case just for making a serial number column as explained in [**the answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597619/optimizing-mysql-order-by-rand/16597706#16597706) of the previous question where you get this from.

The `const` is not used as a keyword here ... so don't be '**`const`-fused**' by that. It is just a given name to `(select @rn := 0)` ... It could have been any other name like `A`, `B`, `oops`, `aah`, `etc` ... (see the second link below)

See example use in the folowing links to better understand the [***User-Defined Variables***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html):

[**Create a Cumulative Sum Column in MySQL**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql)

[**MySql: Select Query- Make A Cumulative Sum Column**](http://develop-for-fun.blogspot.com/2012/06/mysql-select-query-make-cumulative-sum.html)